# org-capture, wrong-type-argument, expand-file-name

Tags: org-capture

I often see this problem when I org-capture

What I do is open this quasar-agenda buffer and kill it.

After that, the command works.

Any idea how to troubleshoot this?;)

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument stringp nil)
  expand-file-name(nil)
  userlock--check-content-unchanged("~/agenda/quasar-agenda.org")
  userlock--ask-user-about-supersession-threat("~/agenda/quasar-agenda.org")
  #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode -0x71e50740e079a7a>)()
  combine-change-calls-1(117694 117694 #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode -0x71e50740e079a7a>))
  org-paste-subtree(1 "* TODO %?\n[2023-05-07 Sun 09:33]\n[[file:/mnt/b53d6..." for-yank)
  org-capture-place-entry()
  org-capture-place-template(nil)
  org-capture(nil)
  funcall-interactively(org-capture nil)
  call-interactively(org-capture nil nil)
  command-execute(org-capture)
```

Comment: You should at least include your capture template in your question.